# Solace JCSMP message acknowledgement via message-id

Tags: jms, solace

I have a Spark application, which uses the Solace JCSMP API to receive TextMessages. Currently we use the `client_ack` mode and call `textMessage.acknowledge()` to ack the messages (after storing the message content into SparkSession's memory).

However, for this approach, we need to have the `TextMessage` instance itself to call the `.acknowledge()` function on it.

For our case, it would be a better solution, if we could somehow acknowledge a message by using only the message-id, but not the Message class itself. Does anyone know if this is possible (and how)?

Hint: If it would help, we could also switch from Solace JCSMP to Solace JMS API.